# Populate a TypeScript interface from a JSON returned by an API

Tags: typescript

I have an API which is returning an error as of following structure:

```json
  error: { message: "entry doesn't exist", code: '4', target: 'uuid' }
```

I want to populate an interface of this:

```js
export interface RestError {
  error: {
    target: string;
    message: string;
    code: string;
    arguments?: {
      message: string;
      code: string;
    }[];
  };
}
```

Now from the API returned object structue I want to create an interface of the type `RestError`.

How can I do it by using `JSON.parse(restErrorObject)`.

If I just do it like this:

```
    console.log('API ERROR:', err?.response?.data);
    const dataParsed: RestError = JSON.parse(err?.response?.data);
```

It failed with the message that the `err?.response?.data` is not a proper JSON.

```
[Nest] 23636   - 03/26/2023, 8:09:00 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 +20532ms
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Of course I can write an util method like this:

```js
  formatErrorMessage(errorMsg): string {
    if (isUndefined(errorMsg)) {
      return undefined;
    }
    const { target, message, code } = errorMsg.error;
    // Manually populating the interface from the error message .. is this good??
    const resError: RestError = !isUndefined(errorMsg.error.arguments)
      ? { error: { target, message, code, arguments: [...errorMsg.error.arguments] } }
      : { error: { target, message, code } };
    return JSON.stringify(resError);
  },
```

However I am querying this portion of comment?

```
    // Manually populating the interface from the error message .. is this good??
```

Is there a better, smarter way of populating the RestError interface from the API error response object such that my portion of code is typed as well as looks nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you are passing an object to `JSON.parse()`. Also, it sounds like you are mixing up the type level, where you tell Typescript what type an object is, and the data level, where you create objects. You do not need to change an object to change its type in Typescript.

So first, you should check that if `err?.response?.data` is not undefined, it is really a string containing data in **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation.

To be clear:

```
const json: string = '{"foo": 1}' // this is a JSON
const noJson = {foo: 1} // this is an object, not a JSON
```

To `JSON.parse()`, you can only pass a JSON (and some primitives like null or numbers), but not objects. If your response is a JSON, you can put it in. Typescript has no way of knowing what the string will be parsed to, so the return type is `any`. But you can tell it what it is:

```
const errorData: string | undefined = err?.response?.data
const dataParsed: RestError | undefined = errorData && JSON.parse(errorData)
```

If your return data already is an object, there is no point in parsing it again (unless you want to see an error), and there is really no point in turning it into a JSON and parsing it again, since you just want to indicate to typescript what kind of object it is.

Doing that depends on what `err.response.data` is typed as (which you didn't say in your question).

If it is `any`, you can simply do:

```
const errorData: RestError | undefined = err?.response?.data
```

Otherwise, you will have to use `as`:

```
const errorData = err?.response?.data as RestError | undefined
```

And that should be it. No additional function necessary. Does that work for you? Does it make sense?

Comment: Thank You @moritz-ringler. Makes sense now.
Actually the REST error type is any. I mean it's not known as it's 3rd party library without a typing.

Answer (score 1):

I think one solution would be to use [`zod`(A TypeScript-first schema validation with static type inference)](https://zod.dev/?id=basic-usage). To use this first you need to create your schema.

```
import { z } from "zod";

const ResponseErrorSchema = z.object({
    error: z.object({
        target: z.string(),
        message: z.string(),
        code: z.string()
    })
  });
```

And then you can call [`ResponseErrorSchema.Parse(data)` method to check the data is valid or not](https://zod.dev/?id=parse). To extract the TypeScript type of any [schema you can use `z.infer<typeof mySchema>`](https://zod.dev/?id=type-inference)

```
type RestError = z.infer<typeof ResponseErrorSchema>;
const response = {error: { message: "entry doesn't exist", code: '4', target: 'uuid' }}
const result: RestError = ResponseErrorSchema.parse(response);
```

Comment: Thank You @abdul-niyas-p-m. 
May be this one right now I do not need. 
But definitely I need it later on for the 3rd party response validation.
Thanks for pointing this.